# Is there any vscode extension that can provide an alternative python debug console that works like a standard terminal?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

The python debug console for vscode has a input area (single line) where you can evaluate python code in the current context while stopped in a breakpoint. Then the output of the evaluation goes to an output area above the input area.
[image]

I'd prefer to have the input and outputs one after the other in one area, like in a standard python terminal. Is there any extension for vscode that would provide a debug console of this type? I've been searching for a while but no success so far.

Just a bit more of information so you know where I'm coming from. I know a lot of developers just use print statements or logs for debugging, that's the case in my company. I'm more of a researcher and the type of code I write is very mathematical. I often don't know what's the best algorithm/method and I find I'm more productive when I can interact with the results, plot intermediate results and try different math on the spot. In fact I discover/write most of the method code while stopped in a breakpoint. Also, I often have diagnosis code blocks in comments after a blocks of maths. I run these code blocks while in debug mode to diagnose if the method is doing what I expect with some new data. This is a common workflow in matlab, which even has default keybidings to execute code blocks F9, and commented code blocks shift-F9. Admittedly, I prefer to use python. And I've been recreating this workflow with WingIDE, and I think I could probably do the same with PyCharm and Spyder. However, we moved all our system to use docker containers and vscode deals with the container very well. So I'm trying to reproduce my workflow with vscode. I don't like the single line input in the vscode debug console because I'll be pasting these diagnosis code blocks while in debugging.